# Best practice for multiple vagrant boxes

Tags: git, vim, emacs, ssh, vagrant

How should a developer manage multiple vagrant boxes in terms of IDE and placement of git/svn/hg client. There are two approaches:

1 - Put git/svn/hg client and IDE (emacs, vim, ...) in the host OS and connect to boxes by using SSH or synced folders to edit/commit code.

2 - Put everything inside the vagrant box.

I want to know which method is preferred and what advantages/disadvantages each of them has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that depends highly on the personal preference, your usual workflow as well as what you use Vagrant for. If you work on Chef or puppet you can use frameworks like kitchen or included provisioners (https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/plugins/provisioners.html) and not deal with anything inside of the VM.

My personal preference is to use synced folders for the code (that can be anywhere in my $HOME), editing them on the host OS and testing it in the VM. Depending on the case that could mean having one terminal for vim, another one with a vagrant ssh session, most times using tmux with 'tail -f logfile' etc. In other cases it is often sufficient for me to use the `vagrant provision` feature by executing (shell) commands defined in the Vagrantfile.

Personal I prefer to only use the Vagrant box for the actual job tasks. For me the benefit of using shared/synced folders is that as developer I can use the tools to write/modify the files I want without the need to install editors, tools (e.g. for code style) or dotfiles on the VM as well as frequent executing `vagrant destroy -y && vagrant up` since I prefer a clean environment to avoid any conflicts of previous steps. But that is my personal preference. You can always modify the VM base box and save it to avoid repeating these installation steps.

A pre-build base box with all the needed tools has their own benefits if you want to share a 'golden image' with co-workers or provide it to new employees. That is especially helpful if you need to install the developer tools for all the libraries or compilers. But even then I personally would prefer my outside of the VM workflow :)

Comment: But by having IDE on host OS, in order to have features like auto-completion you need to install some of devbox libraries on the host OS.